# Show $S_n=\mathbb{Z}_2 \rtimes A_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Good day all!

EDIT: This is a duplicate:[$\mathbb S_n$ as semidirect product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/916698/mathbb-s-n-as-semidirect-product?rq=1)

I have a question (this is *not* homework, rather, I am studying for a test and would like to know how to do this)

Show $S_n=\mathbb{Z}_2 \rtimes A_n$.

Here $A_n$ is the group of even permutations

$S_n$ is the group of permutations

Intuitively I can understand that when you take the semi direct product of {$0,1$} with $A_n$ you would get all the permutations but im not sure how to say it quantitatively. Also, in this can I can also see that $A_n$ is a normal subroup of $S_n$.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: let $sign:S_n\rightarrow Z_2$ be the signature morphism. $Ker(sign)=A_n$ and $sign$ has a splitting which sends $-1$ to a transposition.

Comment: How is this morphism defined? I see how this proves that it is a semi direct product, but how is the mapping actually defined? What do you mean by saying the morphism "has a splitting"?

Comment: you can write $s=t_1...t_n$ where $t_i$ is a transposition, $sign(s)=(-1)^n$.

Comment: ah. ok this is good. Thanks!