# $S_n \cong A_n \rtimes \{1,-1\} $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, group-isomorphism, semidirect-product

I have seen this question already a few times, but I still do not understand the actual answer. I have to prove the isomorphism between $S_n$ and the semidirect product of $\{1,-1\}$ and $A_n$. I am a bit new to the semidirect product, hence my confusion.

So far I figured I have to do something with the parity of the permutations in $S_n$. And I need to definie a homomorphism $\rho: \{1,-1\} \to \text{Aut($A_n$)}$, I really do not know where to start.

Any tips?

Comment: It is explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/916698/mathbb-s-n-as-semidirect-product), for example, how to define $\rho$ (see also the comments to the answers).

Comment: Surely it's $S_n \cong A_n\rtimes  \{1,-1\} $?

Comment: @DietrichBurde ok I was a bit confused about that, but I think I get it now. Then the homomorphism $f: \{1,−1\}\rtimes A_n \to S_n$, would be defined as $f(\sigma,\tau)=\sigma\tau $. Ker(f)=id, thus injective, and surjective because of the cardinalities are the same?

Comment: @Josephine No, because $\sigma\in\{1, -1\}$ is not a permutation (so $\sigma\tau$ makes no sense!). Instead, you should pick an element $\sigma\in S_n\setminus A_n$ which has order two, and set $f(-1, id):=\sigma$, and set $f(1, \tau):=\tau$. Then $f(-1, \tau)=\sigma\tau$.

Comment: (Also, the map $\rho$ corresponds to conjugation. So $\rho(-1):\tau\mapsto\sigma^{-1}\tau\sigma$ and $\rho(1):\tau\mapsto\tau$.

Comment: @user1729 I guess I skipped a stepped, in the explaination mentioned by Dietrich, it says to take the subgroup \{id, (ab)\} that is isomorphic to \{1, -1\}. Then I use that subgroup for the rest